# how to group an ID field and select rows having highest value in another field PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I don't know what *title* I should give for my *question* (never mind it).

below given is my *select query*

```
select gtab04.product,gtab05.productid,gtab05.mrp, gtab05.ptr,gtab05.ssr,gtab07.patent from gtab05 inner 
join gtab07 on gtab05.patentid=gtab07.patentid inner join gtab04 on 
gtab05.productid=gtab04.productid  where gtab05.qty-gtab05.iqty > 0 order by productid
```

and this will return `500+` rows, see the below sample,

```
product           |productid   |mrp     |ptr  |ssr  |patent
------------------+------------+--------+-----+-----+----------------- 
IBUGESIC Plus Tab |200         |12.80000|9.85 |8.87 |CIPLA LTD 
ANGICAM 2.5 Tab   |267         |9.00000 |6.93 |6.44 |BLUE CROSS LABORATORIES 
ANGICAM 2.5 Tab   |267         |5.00000 |6.93 |6.24 |BLUE CROSS LABORATORIES 
ANGICAM 2.5 Tab   |267         |5.00000 |6.93 |6.44 |BLUE CROSS LABORATORIES 
ANGICAM 2.5 Tab   |267         |5.00000 |7.359|6.24 |BLUE CROSS LABORATORIES 
ANGICAM 5 Mg Tab  |268         |14.00000|10.78|10.03|BLUE CROSS LABORATORIES 
ANGICAM 5 Mg Tab  |268         |12.00000|11.44|9.7  |BLUE CROSS LABORATORIES 
ANGICAM BETA Tab  |269         |17.00000|13.09|12.17|BLUE CROSS LABORATORIES 
ANGICAM BETA Tab  |269         |15.00000|13.9 |11.78|BLUE CROSS LABORATORIES 
HIBESOR 25 TAB    |270         |9.00000 |6.93 |6.44 |BLUE CROSS LABORATORIES
```

i would like to modify the above *result* as following..

```
product           |productid   |mrp     |ptr  |ssr  |patent
------------------+------------+--------+-----+-----+----------------- 
IBUGESIC Plus Tab |200         |12.80000|9.85 |8.87 |CIPLA LTD 
ANGICAM 2.5 Tab   |267         |9.00000 |6.93 |6.44 |BLUE CROSS LABORATORIES 
ANGICAM 5 Mg Tab  |268         |14.00000|10.78|10.03|BLUE CROSS LABORATORIES 
ANGICAM BETA Tab  |269         |17.00000|13.9 |11.78|BLUE CROSS LABORATORIES 
HIBESOR 25 TAB    |270         |9.00000 |6.93 |6.44 |BLUE CROSS LABORATORIES
```

- my criteria : need to *GROUP* `productid` and from each *group* taking `product`'s having `max(mrp)`.

---

what i have tried as far as now.

```
    With cte as (
    select gtab04.product,gtab05.productid,gtab05.mrp, gtab05.ptr,gtab05.ssr,patent from gtab05 
    inner join gtab07 on gtab05.patentid=gtab07.patentid inner join gtab04 on 
    gtab05.productid=gtab04.productid  where qty-iqty > 0 order by productid limit 10
    )
    select productid,max(cte.mrp) as mrp  from cte group by productid order by  productid
    )

         RESULT
    --------------
   productid | mrp
          200|12.80000
          267|9.00000
          268|14.00000
          269|17.00000
          270|9.00000
```

---

Comment: Question: does this table have a primary key?

Comment: I see it is the result of a JOIN (so it is a table *expression*) This Texp's PK is a function of the join-conditions and the base tables's PKs. In any case: your question in fact is a dedupping/find-the-first kind of problem.

Comment: `my criteria : need to GROUP productid and from each group taking product's having max(mrp).` What if there are ties? (two tuples sharing the same mrp == max(mrp) in a group of equal productid's)

Comment: Your query is ambiguous. We cannot see where the columns `patent` or `qty-iqty` come from. Add table-qualification where the origin is not obvious to the reader.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter > Your query is ambiguous. We cannot see where the columns patent or qty-iqty come from >> FIXED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`distinct on` combined with `order by`

```
select distinct on (productid) 
    gtab04.product,
    productid,
    gtab05.mrp,
    gtab05.ptr,
    gtab05.ssr,
    patent
from
    gtab05
    inner join
    gtab07 using(patentid)
    inner join
    gtab04 using(productid)
where qty-iqty > 0
order by productid, gtab05.mrp desc
```

If there is any other untie criteria add it to the `order by` clause

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "using"
LINE 13:     gtab04 on using(productid)

Comment: @keet Ok. Just took `on` out.

Comment: ERROR:  column "gtab04.product" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 2:     gtab04.product,

Comment: @keet Fixed. It is without the `grou by`

Comment: This (now fixed) should probably be the accepted answer.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter can you please tell how this works ?

Comment: @keet: I've added another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Reusing the original CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
    select gtab04.product
       ,gtab05.productid ,gtab05.mrp, gtab05.ptr, gtab05.ssr
       ,patent -- NEEDS alias-designation
    from gtab05 
    inner join gtab07 on gtab05.patentid = gtab07.patentid -- NOT USED ...
    inner join gtab04 on gtab05.productid = gtab04.productid
    where qty-iqty > 0 -- NEEDS alias-designation
    order by productid -- NEEDS alias-designation
    -- limit 10
    )
SELECT * FROM cte t0
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT * FROM cte t1
   WHERE t1.productid = t0.productid
   AND t1.mrp > t0.mrp
   )
order by  productid
   ;
```

Comment: i have tried this _answer_ but it doesn't `GROUP` _productid_

Comment: You don't need to group. You only want to find the max of a "group"

Answer (score 0):

After clarifications in the question, I think this variant should perform faster:

```
SELECT g4.product, g5.productid, g5.mrp, g5.ptr, g5.ssr, g7.patent
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (productid)
          productid, mrp, ptr, ssr, patentid
   FROM   gtab05
   WHERE  qty > iqty
   ORDER  BY productid, mrp DESC
   ) g5
JOIN   gtab07 g7 USING (patentid)
JOIN   gtab04 g4 USING (productid);
```

Basically it's using `DISTINCT ON`, like [@Clodoaldo already provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25285558/939860). Detailed explanation for that:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Two things changed:

- It's cheaper to eliminate duplicates before joining to more tables. The benefit grows with the number of rows per group. I am assuming, that joining to `gtab07` and `gtab04` does not produce more duplicates.
- The `WHERE` condition can be simplified to `WHERE  qty > iqty`. Slightly shorter and faster.
  However, *if* that conditions is *selective* (less than ~ 5% of the table qualify), and you have to run this query a lot (and the gain outweighs the cost of index maintenance), then keep your original condition and support it with a [functional index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-expressional.html):

  ```
  CREATE INDEX gtab05_qty_iqty_idx ON gtab05((qty - iqty));
  ```

Run `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to test performance.

Comment: `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` of @ClodoaldoNeto 's [Answer](http://explain.depesz.com/s/fUVq) and [This Answer](http://explain.depesz.com/s/cCn)